# Interpret the meaning of one line of Python3 code

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner for Python3. Here I have one question to bother you. In the function below:

```
def highlight_min(s): 
    '''
    highlight the minimum in a Series red.
    '''
    is_max = s == s.min()
    return ['background-color: red' if v else '' for v in is_max]
```

What does `is_max = s == s.min()` mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s` appears to be an array of some sort. The result of `is_max` in this operation will be a boolean type array the same size as `s`. Any element in `s` that is the same as the minimum of the array `s` will have the value `True`, else it will have the value `False` .

The following line is a loop through `is_max` that returns a python list. `if v` queries if an element is `True` in `is_max` and assigns the string `'background-color: red'` if it is or an empty string if not.

I suspect that the function was copied from the original probably called 'highlight_max' and `is_max` should really be `is_min`.

Comment: I copied the code from a website since I do not understand it. It should be ```is_min```, otherwise it makes no sense.